# Is .webmanifest supported by SharePoint Online? How can I create SharePoint Online Progressive Web Application with supported webmanifest file?

Tags: angular, sharepoint, progressive-web-apps, sharepoint-online, web-manifest

I am trying to create a SharePoint Online Progressive Web Application using the build generated using Angular 8 PWA.
I am able to get the service worker and the application functional. However, the webmanifest file is not loading properly.

I have create a new ASPX page in SharePoint and added the webmanifest file this way:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SC/SiteName/mobile/SitePages/manifest.webmanifest" />
```

In chrome developer tools, the manifest file is always pending for download:

Without this, I am unable to get the "Add to Homescreen" feature while browsing from mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. SharePoint Supports Manifest File. The reason it was not working is being treated as cross origin request.

Adding  crossorigin="use-credentials" at the end of the manifest link fixed the issue:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.webmanifest" crossorigin="use-credentials" />
```